# JavaScript - how to change checkbox background?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I want to change background of checkbox without using jQuery (if is that possible of course), because I'm not familiar with that library.

HTML:

```
    <form name="checkBox">
        <input onchange="checkbox()" type="checkbox" class="cbox" />
    </form>
```

JS:

```
function checkbox(){
    var checkbox = document.getElementByClass('cbox');
    if(document.getElementById('cbox').checked === true){
        checkbox.style.background = "url('uncheck.png')";
    }else{
        checkbox.style.background = "url('check.png')";
    }
}
```

Comment: You have specified a `class`, and listening on `id` - Change `class='cbox'` to `id='cbox'`

Comment: It is still invalid - `document.getElementByClass` It should be `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: I don't think you can set a `background-image` for checkbox.  You can, however, communicate the state of a checkbox via its label.  See my solution that uses only CSS.  And here's a fiddle that shows that background-image for checkbox is not being set: http://jsfiddle.net/g7dM2/.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing class names and ID's. Try this.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="checkBox">
    <input onchange="checkbox()" type="checkbox" id="cbox" />
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
function checkbox(){
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('cbox');
    if(checkbox.checked === true){
        checkbox.style.background = "url('uncheck.png')";
    }else{
        checkbox.style.background = "url('check.png')";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea i found out that after i posted this question.I triend with tout one and everything is same.. Default checkbox background..

Answer (score 0):

How about a pure CSS solution without any need to use images: http://jsfiddle.net/7qcE9/1/.

HTML:

```
<form name="checkBox">
    <input type="checkbox" id = "checkbox1" />
    <label for = "checkbox1"></label>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form > input[type = "checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

form > label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

form > input[type = "checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    content:'\2714';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a reference to the checkbox using `this` in the inline handler as follows:

html

```
<form name="checkBox">
    <input onchange="checkbox(this)" type="checkbox" class="cbox" />
</form>
```

js

```
function checkbox(elm){ // elm now refers to the checkbox
 if(elm.checked === true){
    elm.style.background = "url('uncheck.png')";
 }else{
    elm.style.background = "url('check.png')";
 }
}
```

So that you can use the function for `n` number of elements.

Comment: I triend this one and still checkbox has default background, everythign is still same.Maybe something other?

Comment: @Wiruspwns well the code [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/2dWxj/) maybe it's something else..? please provide a demo with the images where it doesn't work.